# Do I use “扔掉” or “倒掉” to expressing getting rid of 死水？

Tags: translation, grammar

I know this is very specific, but I was looking for a translation for standing/stagnant water (context: mosquitoes), but found out it `死水｀(if that's incorrect though, someone please kindly notify me). However, a new question popped up. What is the verb used for handing 死水？ In English, I would say something such as "get rid of".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`死水` usually refers to the water size of a pond or lake. You probably want to use `积水` instead. Then you can say `清除积水`, for example `清除房屋和院子里各处的积水`.

Comment: Doesn't using ｀房屋｀imply water indoors, say in the living room or in a bedroom?

Comment: yes it does. 积水 could be anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

扔掉 - an action of `throwing` away.  You can't grab water and throw it, so it's not suitable
倒掉 - to `pour` out / away.  It make sense to use 倒掉, but a common way will be what most other answer suggested - 清除 - to clean up

Also stagnant water = 积水

Answer (score 0):

I think 清除 is a good choice as answered by Wang Dingwei.
By the way, since 死水 can also mean water or even liquid that is not fluid. And it's often used to reference the dirty water.